# Whats wrong with setprecision in my compiler?

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8

I've been having trouble with my compiler, NetBeans. It seems that using setprecision is not doing anything. Here is the code needed to see what's happening. This  part of the program check to see if a triangle it possible given three sides.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   double SideA,SideB,SideC,p,a,longest;

   cout<<"Enter the length of each side of your triangle. Press enter after each number."<<endl;

   cin>>SideA>>SideB>>SideC;

   cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3); 
   if(SideA+SideB<=SideC||SideA+SideC<=SideB||SideB+SideC<=SideA||SideA<=0||SideB<=0||SideC<=0)
   {
        cout<<"The length of the first side is "<<SideA<<"."<<endl;
        cout<<"The length of the second side is "<<SideB<<"."<<endl; 
        cout<<"The length of the third side is "<<SideC<<"."<<endl; 
        cout<<"This triangle is impossible."<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I want the side length to be rounded to the nearest thousandths when shown on the screen. It does not do this with my NetBeans compiler. I've put this into online compilers, and it works there.

Here's my C++ configuration in NetBeans:

[image: C++ configuration]

The sample input data is: **6.6666666, 5.4444444, 1**

The expected output is: **6.667, 5.443, 1.000**

The actual output is: **6.66667, 5.44444, 1**

[image: Test screenshot]

Comment: Why not use one of the many free, high-quality compilers like GCC, Clang or even Visual Studio Express? There's no reason to be stuck with Netbeans.

Comment: It's for a college class, the professor insists we use netbeans :/

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE anyway; the OP is likely using gcc or clang under the hood (or mingw if on Windows).

Comment: @tadman Regarding, _"There's no reason to be stuck with Netbeans"_, NetBeans provides an IDE for the C++ compiler of your choice, such as **gcc**. NetBeans itself does not provide its own C++ compiler, and if there is a compiler issue it's nothing to do with NetBeans.

Comment: [1] Please update your question to include a screen shot of your C++ configuration: **Tools > Options > C/C++**, then click the **Build Tools** tab. [2] Also provide some sample input data to demonstrate the problem, and state the actual and expected results.

Comment: What *is* your compiler? Netbeans is not a compiler, it is an IDE. What C++ compiler are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving correctly. You are using `cout` to display the values of double variables, and [by default it will use a precision of 6](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/formatting.pdf):

> A double value will be printed using a general format that usually
>   works fine to represent a number in a small amount of space. The basic
>   amount of space used is determined by the precision. **The default
>   precision is 6, which means up to 6 significant digits are used to
>   represent the number. This counts digits both to the left and the
>   right of the decimal point. Fewer digits are printed if the result is
>   accurate**; e.g. trailing zeros at the right of the decimal point are
>   not printed. As shown in the example below, as the number increases in
>   size, places to the right of the decimal point will be dropped, and
>   the result rounded off as needed to stay within 6 digits.

The text in bold font explains the output you obtained for your sample input: **6.66667**, **5.44444**, and **1**.

You can limit the precision to obtain the results you want by using `cout.precision()` or `setprecision()`. This is also detailed in the linked article.

Finally, note that this is issue has nothing to do with NetBeans. You can confirm this by using **g++** to compile your code from the command line. When you run it you will get the same results, even though you are not using NetBeans.